# How do I debug a "silent" Process failure?

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, process, acrobat

I am printing PDF files like this.
It works fine for most of my printers:

```
Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal uPath As String, ByVal uPrinter As String)

    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    psi.Verb = "printto"
    psi.Arguments = uPrinter
    psi.CreateNoWindow = False
    psi.FileName = uPath

    Dim nProc As New Process
    nProc.StartInfo = psi
    nProc.Start()

    If nProc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("failed!!!")
    End If

    DoSleep(3000)

    Do While Not modEnvironment.IsPrinterQueueEmpty()
        DoSleep(2000)
    Loop

    Try
        nProc.CloseMainWindow()
    Catch ex As Exception
         Debug.Assert(False)
    End Try
    nProc.Close()

End Sub
```

This works fine for some printers.

For one printer, it does not work.
The name I have given it is

```
"Canon MB2700 series Printer Wifi"
```

As one can guess, it's a Wifi printer. But I am not aware that Wifi printers have to be treated differently than locally connected printers.

There is no obvious error thrown or different process ExitCode, it just does not print.

I have compared the printer names again and again, I do not see any obvious spelling mistake or so.

That is why I would like to ask how I could debug what goes wrong in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!

```
psi.Arguments = chrw(34) & uPrinter & chrw(34)
```

Obviously the spaces were a problem, so the name had to be put in " ".

Comment: FYI you can escape a quote character using another quote character e.g. `psi.Arguments = $"""{uPrinter}"""`

Comment: @Craig That is super hard to read, that is why I instead prefer a custom function named Quote(). But I wanted to keep my answer simple.